# How do I remove the acrylic knob on my faucet?

Tags: bathroom-fixtures

[image]

Faucet with one knob does hot & cold. Single screw. Plain old crystal knob. Just want to take off knob & replace it with brand new one. Don't know how to remove the knob.

Comment: It may be stuck on. You may be able to wiggle it back and forth and get it loose. The core of the knob is usually metal which engages the flutes on the stem and this can fuse by corrosion over time. It may be irreversibly stuck on. Any force strong enough to break it free may just fracture the plastic. You may just have to replace the faucet. A possibility to try is a tool like a steering wheel or pulley puller. You would reinsert the screw and screw it part way in, then the tool presses on the screw and pulls on the plastic. I think there is a good chance this would just break the knob.

Comment: You best bet is to clean the knob in place and if that doesn't work, replace the entire faucet.

Comment: My advice is squirt a little wd40 in the screw hole and wait 12 hours or more.  Add another squirt a few time while your wauting.  Then turn off the water and pull.  You might also have luck turning the valve all the way in each direction and giving just a little more force in that same direction as you pull.  A comparable faucet isn't very expensive.  In fact looking at home depot new faucet can be had in the $40-50 range, and the knob you need is $11 alone.

Comment: Petroleum lubricants will often weaken plastics and cause them to fracture. Silicone lubricants are safer to use with plastic, but silicone is expensive and I don't of any silicone which could be sprayed in the screw hole. Puller tool http://www.homedepot.com/p/Capri-Tools-3-in-3-Jaw-Gear-Puller-CP10500/207008170?cm_mmc=Shopping|THD|google|&mid=sH9ymKNyB|dc_mtid_8903tb925190_pcrid_153597337654_pkw__pmt__product_207008170_slid_&gclid=Cj0KEQjwn_3GBRDc8rCnup-1x8wBEiQAdw3OAcpftaaKnuOmU6ItASWY9JNkAL0uD2gy7HrHQkdYx6IaAhgH8P8HAQ

Comment: You could try **tapping** gently and alternately on opposite sides on the underside of the knob with a hammer while pulling up on the handle, but be aware that anything you do like this could break the knob or the internals of the faucet.

Answer (score 1):

It's in a splined (fluted) shaft and it pulls straight out.   It's common for them to be a little sticky.

If you just leave it like that with the screw out (don't lose it) it may work loose from the stress of normal usage.  Let time do your loosening :) If there are a lot of threads engaging the faucet, you could try loosening the screw about halfway and leaving it like that.  Then it wouldn't come off entirely, just get sloppy.

Answer (score 0):

You might try a faucet pulling tool like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000I1ARPO). They are inexpensive.